# how to create hyperlinks when transforming xml to xsl-fo using xlst?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

I would like to transform any http/s based url inside random text to be automatically tagged with xsl-fo , where the random text might contains one or more http/s based url.

So the http/s url is not part of an attribute or the only content of a node, but part of text within a node.

For example: the source

```
<misc>
  <comment>Yada..yada..yadda, see http://www.abc.com. 
           Bla..bla..bla.. http://www.xyz.com</comment>
</misc>
```

Will be transform into something like:

```
<fo:block>
  Yada..yada..yadda, see <fo:basic-link external-destination="http://www.abc.com">http://www.abc.com</fo:basic-link>.
  Bla..bla..bla.. <fo:basic-link external-destination="http://www.xyz.com">http://www.xyz.com</fo:basic-link>
<fo:/block>
```

The library we are using is Apache FOP and Xalan-J.

Comment: Are you using XSLT version 1 or 2? The latter has much better string manipulation functions from XPath 2.0, including regular expression matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use a pure XSLT method, you could use this:

```
<xsl:template match="comment">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:call-template name="dig-links">
      <xsl:with-param name="content" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="dig-links">
  <xsl:param name="content" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($content, 'http://')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($content, 'http://')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="url" select="concat('http://', substring-before(substring-after(concat($content, ' '), 'http://'), ' '))"/>
      <fo:basic-link>
        <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($url, string-length($url), 1) = '.'">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring($url, 1, string-length($url)-1)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$url"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$url"/>
      </fo:basic-link>
      <xsl:call-template name="dig-links">
        <xsl:with-param name="content" select="substring-after($content, $url)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$content"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It's not a perfect solution however, thus if you have typos such as two dots at the end of a url, the external-destination attribute will get one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what xsl:fo means, but if you have access to the xslt file that actually does the conversion, you might convert it yourself by using xml string functions mentioned [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string). If you have access to the transformed output only, you still can

- apply another xslt that does what you want or
- transform it yourself using SAX and using the java regex functions